# Symfony controller as a service argument not injected

Tags: symfony

I have this controller:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class AjaxEntityController
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    ...
}
```

And this is my services.yml:

```
services:
    tapir_form.ajax_entity_controller:
        class: Tapir\FormBundle\Controller\AjaxEntityController
        arguments: [ '@doctrine' ]
```

But when I try to access this controller (by it's URL), I get this error:

Type error: Argument 1 passed to Tapir\FormBundle\Controller\AjaxEntityController::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, none given, called in /..../var/cache/dev/jms_diextra/controller_injectors/TapirFormBundleControllerAjaxEntityController.php on line 13

I've searched for this problem, and found lots of cases where the controller was not declared as a service or the arguments parameter was missing, but it's not my case.

I cleared the cache, added @Route(service="tapir_form.ajax_entity_controller") to my controller class, just in case. Of course I have my TapirFormExtension

```
$loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
$loader->load('services.yml');
```

If I remove the mandatory parameter from the constructor, the service works (I mean the controller action is called, no exception).
This is the first time I use a controller as a service. Other services like form types are working with a similar configuration.

I'm using Symfony 2.7.3, PHP 5.6.13, Linux.

What else can be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to change your routing information to specify the controller as a service:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html#referring-to-the-service

Comment: As @Cerad stated... You problem is that you probably defined route in `routing.yml` file, and later you defined service in `@Route` annotation..

Comment: That was it Cerad, thanks! I was using "Bundle:Controller:action" instead of "servicename:method" in my routing.yml.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Symfony 3.3** you can use autowiring:

```
# app/services/services.yml
services:
    Tapir\FormBundle\Controller\AjaxEntityController:
        autowire: true
```

Or for more controllers, **[PSR-4 service autodiscovery](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/#4-use-psr-4-based-service-autodiscovery-and-registration)**:

```
# app/services/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    Tapir\:
        resource: src/Tapir/{Controller}
```